# How to convert local date-time string to Unix timestamp (GMT)?

Tags: bash, date, timestamp, utc

```
time_var="6/23/2016 3:20:00 AM"
```

(this is in EDT)

We need to get unix timestamp for this variable after converting its value to GMT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `-u` flag while passing the date with `-d`:

```
$ time_var="6/23/2016 3:20:00 AM"
$ date -d"$time_var EDT" -u
Thu Jun 23 07:20:00 UTC 2016
```

Note I also appended `EDT` to your date.

From `man date`:

```
   -d, --date=STRING
          display time described by STRING, not 'now'
   -u, --utc, --universal
          print or set Coordinated Universal Time
```

Comment: @SwapnilHarde nice to read that! Remember you can accept the answer then.